# RabbitMQ Error After send JSON message in payload api

Tags: rabbitmq

Here is the content that i send to rabbitmq from postman

http://somthing/api/exchanges/%2f/logstash-logger/publish

```
{"properties": 
{"content-type": "application/json"},
"routing_key": "logstash-key",
"payload":{
"abc": "1.0",
"deg": "XY",
"dhi": "AB",
"jkl": "654654",
"mno": "CREATED",
"pqr": "SYSTEM",
"rst": "1.0",
"uvw": "LOG",
"timestamp": "07/24/2012 9:31:12"
},
"payload_encoding": "string"
}
```

and get this error

> {
>       "error": "bad_request",
>       "reason": "payload_not_string" }

**anyone know? whats the problem ?**

Comment: Are you send the mentioned data as `json`? If Yes, send it as a string.

Comment: yes data is as json , but i want to send in json template

Comment: Use content_type instead of content-type. Let me know if it works.

Comment: i used the content_type on properties but still not working ! and return error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **here is the code that worked for me**

```
    {"properties": 
    {"content_type": "application/json"},
    "routing_key": "logstash-key",
    "payload":
    "{\"Data\" : \"{data}\",\"SequenceNumber\" : {seqNumber},\"DeviceID\" : \"{device}\"}",
    "payload_encoding": "string"
    }
```